# Como fazer um background ultrapassar a div

Tags: html, css

vou citar um exemplo aqui pra ver se vocês entendem oque quero fazer: Vamos supor que você tem um cabeçalho **(header)** com a cor do background **preta** , e um conteúdo **(main)** com a cor do background **cinza**, e tem uma **imagem png** que são umas linhas so para melhorar o design, e eu quero que essa imagem png ocupe o **cabecalho(header)** o **conteudo(main)** juntos? se eu faço por exemplo:

```
<div(com imagem png)> 

 <header></header>

 <main></main>

</div>
```

quando eu adiciono uma cor no **header** ou no **main** ele esconde esse **background** mesmo eu usando o **z-index**, deu pra entende a explicação? kk sou meio leigo pra explicar as coisas.

agora vou mostrar um exemplo que tentei fazer, como vocês podem ver a **imagem png** esta certa do jeito que ela tem que estar, porem a **cor do background do (pagina-onde-encontrar)** e **(conteúdo-onde-encontrar)** estão meio **transparente pra vocês conseguirem ver o png**, porem se eu **colocar a opacidade da cor em 100% ela esconde a imagem png.**

pesquisei sobre e não achei nada do tipo, alguém sabe se da pra fazer isso e qual o jeito certo de fazer se é que isso e possível.

segue abaixo o exemplo e o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma alternativa é usar o bg em um pseudo elemento da div. E não na própria div.

Comment: Como assim? @hugocsl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O `z-index` não funcionará para si, porque o elemento que você quer sobrepor está como filho do elemento que você quer que fique por cima.

A minha sugestão é não usar as linhas como *background* da `div`, mas adicionar as linhas como um elemento `img` e arrumar a sua posição na tela com `position`, `left`, `right` e outros atributos similares.

Answer (score 1):

Show, consegui chegar no resultado que eu queria. e é tão obvio o jeito de fazer kk , basta entender que o position absolut ele vai ate a div pai que tem o position relative, eu não entendia isso por isso não consegui fazer pois descer a imagem do topo ate o roda pé é embaçado.

obrigado amigo pela ajuda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        section {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .a {
            height: 400px;
            background: blueviolet;
        }

        .b {
            height: 400px;
            background: rgb(43, 76, 226);
        }

        img {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="a">Menu</div>
        <div class="b">Conteudo</div>
        <img src="bg-forno.png" alt="">
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que ótimo que conseguiu. De fato, alguns layouts exigem uma estrutura de HTML que não é tão óbvia.